# Cannot Embed HTML with JavaScript

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, html, iframe

I am trying to embed a local HTML file with inline JS on my SharePoint page. The HTML shows up but the JavaScript is blocked. The HTML file embeds, but the JavaScript does not run. Here is the error I am getting in my browsers log:

> Blocked script execution in 'about:srcdoc' because the document's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-scripts' permission is not set.

My embed code is:

```
<iframe sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups allow-forms" src="https://SITE.sharepoint.com/:u:/s/IT/E9GaXihPHsVysRym13iVSQXE4PDfylKU7Ep9qOn0zzOLbn?e=i3d5cd" width="100%" height="500px"></iframe>
```

I've searched high and low, and here are the fixes I've tried:

```
Site Settings > HTML Field Security > selected Allow contributors to insert iframes only from the following domains *inserted mysite.sharepoint.com in list*

SharePoint Admin Center > Settings > Classic Settings > Allow Users to run custom script on personal sites

SharePoint Admin Center > Settings > Classic Settings > Allow Users to run custom script on self-service created sites
```

- Used PowerShell to enable scripts

```
PS C:\Users\Me> Connect-SPOService -URL "https://SITE-admin.sharepoint.com"

PS C:\Users\Me> Set-SPOSite "https://SITE.sharepoint.com/sites/IT" -DenyAddAndCustomizePages $False
```

- Tried directly embedding the html file into my page using different iterations of the URL:

```
directly, using:

https://SITE.sharepoint.com/sites/IT/Shared%20Documents/my_html_file.html?web=1
https://SITE.sharepoint.com/sites/IT/Shared%20Documents/my_html_file.html

and using the "copy link to file" menu, with perms to anyone in the org:
https://SITE.sharepoint.com/:u:/s/IT/E9GaXihPHsVysRym13iVSQXE4PDfylKU7Ep9qOn0zzOLbn?e=i3d5cd
```

- Also tried renaming it to .aspx and repeating the steps above
- Waiting >24 hours after making these admin center/PS changes, and restarting my computer ;)
- Tried the HTML file on another SharePoint site (different tenant). It worked great.

Any help would be most appreciated! I have GA and site owner, so it should not be a permissions issue.

Comment: Custom JavaScript working fine when embedded in another SharePoint tenant?

Comment: @GaneshSanap Yes that is correct